# linear model in tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra

I was trying to generate a simple linear model in Tensorflow. Here is the code ...

```
N        = 400
features = 100
nSteps   = 1000

data = (np.random.randn(N, features), np.random.randint(0, 2, N))

W = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(features,1), name='W')
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(features,1), name='b')
d = tf.constant(data[0], dtype=tf.float32)

result = tf.add( tf.matmul(d, W), b)
```

It turns out that there might be some problem with the dimensions of `b`, but for some reason as far as I can say, they are all ok ...

Not sure why this is throwing an error. Can someone please help?

Note:

```
result = tf.matmul(d, W)
```

This is ok.

I have checked the shape of the result, and is the same as that of `b`. Not really sure what might be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a linear model (i.e. one unit in the output layer), `b` should be a scalar.

Mathematically, for a single observation, you have: `result = WX + b`, where dimensions `W` [1 x features], `X` [features x 1]. Then, `WX` is scalar. Thus `b` should be a scalar.

So you should change `b` to the following, to get the correct linear model and make the dimensions work out:

```
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1,1), name='b')
```